# JS to restrict number of digits to 10 before decimal point

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I want to restrict the number of digits of my currency field in Salesforce to 10 digits before decimal point and 2 digits after decimal point.

Requirement : The input box should stop taking any input once these individual limits are reached.

Below is my function .

Please help me with the events and how to stop input functionalities:

```
function restrictCurrencyValue() {
        alert("Function called");
        var amountValue = document.getElementById("{!$Component.Id1.Id2.Id3}").value;
        alert("xxx"+amountValue);
        var enteredAmount = amountValue;
        //var enteredAmount = val;
        if(enteredAmount == '')
            return false;
        var regExp = /^(?!\.?$)\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,2})?$/; //Declare Regex
        var amountVal = enteredAmount.match(regExp);
```

//Please help out here what should be the next changes to stop keyboard press

```
        if (amountVal == null){
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        }
 }
```

Comment: Blocking user input is unfriendly, much better to just show a message and let the user fix things themselves.

Comment: RobG - The requirement is that the behavior should be how SFDC fixed length text boxes behave. Not allowing user to enter after the limit is reached . In the code snippet here , I have actually tried to show a message if the regex does not match . Can you please take a look at that ?